# Google Apps Script - replaceText - Can't Replace Period, Comma and Question Mark

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am trying to write a google app script, which will find and replace specific words with others in google docs...

I would like " hello " (space, hello, space) to be replaced by " R1 " (space, R1, space)
And if there is any punctuation mark after hello like a period, comma or question mark it should be the same logic:

- `" hello "` to be replaced by `" R1 "`
- `" hello. "` to be replaced by `" R1. "`
- `" hello, "` to be replaced by `" R1, "`
- `" hello? "` to be replaced by `" R1? "`

So I used the following:

```
function docReplace() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  body.replaceText(" hello ", " R1 ");
  body.replaceText(" hello. ", " R1. ");
  body.replaceText(" hello, ", " R1, ");
  body.replaceText(" hello? ", " R1? ");
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, as "." , "," and "?" are regex symbols.

Then, I tried this:

```
function docReplace() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  body.replaceText(" hello ", " R1 ");
  body.replaceText(" hello\. ", " R1. ");
  body.replaceText(" hello\, ", " R1, ");
  body.replaceText(" hello\? ", " R1? ");
}
```

But still doesn't work. Commas and Question marks return as periods.

I would appreciate if anyone could help with the correct code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to achieve the following replacement using Google Apps Script. In this sample, `##` was used as the separator of the values.

  - From

    ```
    ## hello ##
    ## hello. ##
    ## hello, ##
    ## hello? ##
    ```
  - To

    ```
    ## R1 ##
    ## R1. ##
    ## R1, ##
    ## R1? ##
    ```

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? In this modification, `\.`, `\,` and `\?` are modified to `\\.`, `\\,` and `\\?`, respectively.

#### Modified script:

```
function docReplace() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  body.replaceText(" hello ", " R1 ");  // Modified
  body.replaceText(" hello\\. ", " R1. ");  // Modified
  body.replaceText(" hello\\, ", " R1, ");  // Modified
  body.replaceText(" hello\\? ", " R1? ");  // Modified
}
```

#### Reference:

- [replaceText(searchPattern, replacement)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replaceText(String,String))

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: @tylo88 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.